# slim/csrf implementation not rendering custom error message

Tags: php, csrf, slim

slim/csrf not rendering the custom error message.
 why it is not outputting the cutstom error message

```
  $container['csrf'] = function ($c) {
        $guard = new \Slim\Csrf\Guard();
        $guard->setFailureCallable(function ($request, $response, $next) {
            $request = $request->withAttribute("csrf_status", "FAILED");
            return $next($request, $response);
        });
        return $guard;
    };
```

this is my post route

```
    $app->post('/welcome',function($request,$response){
        if ('FAILED' === $request->getAttribute('csrf_status')) {
          return $response->write('fail to validate');
        } else {
            return $this->view->render($response,'welcome.php');
        }

    });
```

it is not outputting the custom error message. it just output
the default text error message(Failed CSRF check!).

Comment: You could ask this question [here](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim-Csrf/issues)